# CS-50 pset4 recover: Why getting segmentation fault?

Tags: c, cs50

It's a solution of CS50-pset4 recover. But why I am getting segmentation fault?
I tried to not access any NULL pointer ar any uninitialized file, but can't figure the way out.
The intent was to copy block of 512B memory from a given file to another if it matches the condition of being a jpeg file. And it is assumed that the jpeg files are stored in a contiguous memory location.
$

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filename
    char *infile = argv[1];
    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }
    FILE *img = NULL;
    unsigned char buffer[512] = {0};
    //char *jpgname = NULL;
    string jpegname = "";
    int jpegnum = 0;       // for keep track of jpeg no. 
    //sprintf(jpgname, "%03d.jpg", jpegnum+1);
    //jpegnum += 1;
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && 
((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
        {
            if (jpegnum > 0)  // if there exist a jpeg file, it should close first
            {
                fclose(img);
           }
            sprintf(jpegname, "%03d.jpg", (jpegnum+1));
            jpegnum += 1;
            img = fopen(jpegname, "w");
            //fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
        }
       else if (jpegnum == 0)
       {
            continue;
        }
        fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
    }
    fclose(img);
    fclose(inptr);

    return 0;
}
```

$

Comment: Make sure `img` is not `NULL` before attempting to close or write to it.

Comment: And also make sure that `img` is not `NULL` before closing it at the end.  It would certainly still be `NULL` at that point if none of the blocks tested had turned out to be JPEGs.

Answer (score 1):

A string literal `""` is assigned to `jpegname` and it is passed to `sprintf()`.
This is bad because

- Modifying string literals is forbidden.
- Even if modifying were allowed, `""` has only 1 element (for the terminating null character) and it won't be enough for saving the filename.

Try using

```
char jpegname[512] = "";
```

instead of

```
string jpegname = "";
```

This change will give modifiable 512-byte buffer to `jpegname`, which will be enough for the filename.

Also note that passing `img`, whose value is `NULL`, to `fclose()` should be bad.

Comment: The dreaded `string` typedef strikes *again*.  I want to have words with whoever designed this curriculum.